# Verb to describe water "hitting" an object from a relatively high place?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Example:

> A pan being **hit** by a continuous flux of tap water.

I think *hit* is too strong for this sentence? Is there a better verb to use?

Comment: If you'd invert the sentence, you'd have a new list of verbs to consider: _The tap water incessantly **dripping** on the pan._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The tap water pitter-pattered on the pan
>
> The pan "pattered" from the dripping tap water.

I admit I allowed myself the guilty pleasure of rephrasing the original sentence; however, consider the verb, [drum](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drum), as an alternative to *hit*.

> A pan being drummed by a continuous flux of tap water

Comment: Thanks! Ha, I think it's perfect. The quote is from a short story I'm writing. And it's about music.

Comment: @janoChen  You should have said so in your question. But I'm glad my suggestion was "bang" on target. :)

Answer (score 0):

Search for hit synonyms. "Struck" for example

Also hit is a single impact, so I would move the continuous

> A pan being continuously struck by tap water.